# sublime text 3 plugin for removing quotes

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to convert [this plugin](https://github.com/daryltucker/MagiclessQuotes/blob/master/magiclessquotes.py) from Sublime Text 2 to Sublime Text 3, but I keep running into this error

```
  File "/Users/macintoshhd/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/magiclessquotesjon.py", line 17, in on_pre_save
    edit = view.begin_edit()
TypeError: begin_edit() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'edit_token' and 'cmd'
```

I know that the API changed between versions and that there is a [porting guide](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/porting_guide.html), but I still am not sure how to get the proper TextCommand or how to use it.

Plugin code here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

__author__ = "Daryl Tucker"

import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RemoveMagicFromMagic(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        replacements = [
            [u'[’‘`]{1}',u'\''],
            [u'[“”]{1}',u'"'],
            [u'[…]{1}',u'...'],
            [u'[—]{1}',u'---'],
            [u'[–]{1}',u'--'],
            [u'[•]{1}',u'*'],
            [u' & ',u' &amp; '],
        ]
        edit = view.begin_edit()
        for replacement in replacements:
            x = view.find_all(replacement[0])
            for position in x:
                view.replace(edit, position, replacement[1])
        view.end_edit(edit)
```

Answer (score 6):

Was able to get it working with an extra callback..

```
class RemoveSmartQuotesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, user_input=None):
        self.edit = edit
        replacements = [
            [u'[’‘`]{1}',u'\''],
            [u'[“”]{1}',u'"'],
            [u'[…]{1}',u'...'],
            [u'[—]{1}',u'---'],
            [u'[–]{1}',u'--'],
            [u'[•]{1}',u'*'],
            [u' & ',u' &amp; '],
        ]
        for replacement in replacements:
            x = self.view.find_all(replacement[0])
            for position in x:
                self.view.replace(edit, position, replacement[1])

class RemoveSmartQuotesWhenSaving(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        view.run_command('remove_smart_quotes')
```

Comment: For your reference: I ran into a similar issue & received an excellent __[solution](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-issue-using-edit-objects-recursively/18400)__ on the Sublime Text forum, which I now greatly prefer to the standard method of working with `edit` objects. Here is a __[working version](https://gist.github.com/Enteleform/8b46387a5e0d9341fc88)__ of the solution mentioned in the thread.  It is implemented as follows: `edit = Edit( view )` & `edit.replace( region, text )`